# How to use if else statement when define a keras model

Tags: keras

I want to define a keras model. There are two inputs to the model and one output. I want to have some if ... else ... statement in the model definition so that when the second input is some meaningful data, the layers inside the if statement is executed while when the second input is None, the layers inside the else statement is executed.  Here are some simple code to illustrate my idea

```
def my_model(input_shape=None):
    input1 = Input(shape=input_shape)
    input2 = Input(shape=input_shape)

    if input2 != None:
        x= Conv2D(32, (3, 3))(input1)
    else:
        x = dense(10)(input1)

    model = Model([input1, input2], x)
    return model
```

I think the above code won't work? But how can I achieve my goal? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Input and output shapes must be fixed in layers. In your example, Conv2D with 32 filters will result in a shape completely different from a Dense with 10 neurons.

There is a possibility, if you guarantee the same output shape, of using "backend functions" inside a "Lambda" layer. But, this will not create trainable layers!

If you do want trainable layers, I suggest you simply create two models, one for data with input2 and another for data without input2. You keep your "if" statement completely outside your models, you use it to separate your training data.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you please elaborate "There is a possibility..."? The output shape is indeed the same for different input2. Sorry that I made a bad example in my code. And I don't need trainable layers. Since I am using this model when testing. Thanks!

Comment: Let me make it more clear. If input2 != None: x = ConvLSTM2D(32,(3,3), stateful=True)(input1, initial_state=[input2, input2] ) else: x = ConvLSTM2D(32, (3,3), stateful=True)(input1).  So I am using input2 to initialize the hidden states of the ConvLSTM2D layer. I only need to set the initial states once, i.e., at the beginning of each time sequence. So the if statement will be only executed once. It won't work if I separate the model into two.